# SELECTing specific information with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database from the following flow-chart:

[image]

Populated according to this:

> 1. There is a book called 'The Lost Tribe'.
> 2. There is a library branch called 'Sharpstown' and one called 'Central'.
> 3. There are at least 20 books in the BOOK table.
> 4. There are at least 10 authors in the BOOK_AUTHORS table.
> 5. Each library branch has at least 10 book titles, and at least two copies of each of those titles.
> 6. There are at least 8 borrowers in the BORROWER table, and at least 2 of those borrowers have more than 5 books loaned to them.
> 7. There are at least 4 branches in the LIBRARY_BRANCH table.
> 8. There are at least 50 loans in the BOOK_LOANS table.
> 9. There must be at least one book written by 'Stephen King'

I am trying to find how many copies of the book titled **The Lost Tribe** are owned by the library branch whose name
is "**Sharpstown**". Now I know that by finding out what the BranchId of **Sharpstown** is I could just run the following query:

`SELECT No_Of_Copies FROM BOOK_COPIES WHERE BookId = 1 and BranchId = 1`

But is there a way to search by using the actual name "**Sharpstown**"? 

 Thank you for your help, I am quite new to SQL SERVER and don't know how specific one user can get with queries.

Comment: You tagged the question with MySQL but then mention SQL Server. These are separate products and the tags should reflect the one you're using. But you should look up on joins.

Comment: GIve it a try to use joins and come back when you have tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For library branch, you could use `IN`

```
SELECT No_Of_Copies FROM BOOK_COPIES
WHERE BookId = 1 
    AND BranchId IN (SELECT BranchId 
                     FROM library_branch
                     WHERE BranchName = 'Sharpstown');
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you will definitely be using this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.

It will look something like this if you wanna use `correlated subquery`:

```
SELECT No_Of_Copies FROM BOOK_COPIES
WHERE BranchId IN (
    SELECT BranchId FROM LIBRARY_BRANCH WHERE BranchName = "Sharpstown") 
AND BookId IN (
    SELECT BookId FROM BOOK WHERE Title = "The Lost Tribe" )
```

Or you could use joins as @Sachin suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Join for that requirement. You have to join `BOOK_COPIES` with `LIBRARY_BRANCH` and `BOOK` table,  then you can find by `BranchName`

```
SELECT No_Of_Copies 
FROM BOOK_COPIES inner join LIBRARY_BRANCH 
on BOOK_COPIES .BranchId = LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchId 
inner join BOOK
on BOOK_COPIES.BookId = BOOK.BookId 
WHERE BOOK.Title = "The Lost Tribe" and LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = "Sharpstown"
```

Comment: Didn't realize I could use Joins like this. Thank you!

Comment: Some times, `join` is faster than subqueries

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
            SELECT No_Of_Copies FROM BOOK_COPIES 
            WHERE BranchId in 
            (
            select BranchId  from library_branch
            where branchname like '%Sharpstown%'
            )
             and BookId in
            (
            select BookId 
            from book where title like 
            '%The Lost Tribe%'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT No_Of_Copies FROM BOOK_COPIES 
 LEFT JOIN  LIBRARY_BRANCH  on BOOK_COPIES.BranchId=LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchId
WHERE BookId = 1 and BranchName = 'Sharpstown'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT No_Of_Copies  
    FROM BOOK_COPIES 
        WHERE BookId=(SELECT BookId FROM BOOK WHERE Title="The Lost Tribe") 
            AND branchid=(SELECT BranchId FROM LIBRARY_BRANCH WHERE BranchName="Sharpstown")
```

Use `Title="The Lost Tribe"` if you are looking for exact match and it will faster then using `Title LIKE "%The Lost Tribe%"`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get the book id dynamically as well, you can use inner join.

```
SELECT BC.NOOFCOPIES FROM
BOOK_COPIES BC INNER JOIN BOOK B ON B.BOOKID = BC.BOOKID
                INNER JOIN BRANCH BR ON BC.BRANCHID = BR.BRANCHID
            WHERE BR.BRANCHNAME = 'SHARPSTOWN';
```